# Will a large number of ANDs be a performance issue in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

i'm new to mySQL. 
i have a books table and i want the users to be able to search through the books and find a specific book.

the books table columns:
   ======================
   publisher
   writer
   name
   price
   publishing date
   etc.

how should i query this table to find a specefic book to have a good performance? what i am doing now is:

```
SELECT name,writer,publisher,price 
FROM books
WHERE publisher='publisher' 
AND writer='wirter' 
AND name='name' 
AND price<='price' 
AND publishingdate>='publishingdate' 
etc.
```

but there are too many ANDs and i think this will kill the server. is there a better method to search a table?
thanks

Comment: It won't kill the server unless you have no column indexes and you're running this query all the time.  Find out which columns are used most often in your `WHERE` clauses, and create an index on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly ok to have multiple like this for the conditions you require.
I wouldn't consider less than a dozen to be excessive.  I've seen queries with 30 `and`s that didn't have performance issues.

It will not 'kill the server' at all.  However this is a good opportunity to try queries, see how long they run and then try to improve them with indexes, other tables, etc.

If performance is an issue due to a large number of records you can add indexes to the various fields.  If you have under 10,000 records I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 4):

You should add indexes to your table to improve performance.

You could try indexing each column individually if you want to support a wide range of user-specified searches on different columns.

If after adding these indexes you still find that a specific query that runs slowly, you may want to add a multi-column index that MySQL can use to improve the performance of that query. You can use `EXPLAIN` to see which indexes a specific query uses.

You should also be aware that adding indexes can improve performance of reads, but it will also decrease the performance of writes to the table. If writing speed is also important, you should be careful to not add many unused indexes.

**Related**

- [`CREATE INDEX` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html)
- [Understanding the Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is fine, it won't kill anything. Try not to optimize prematurely; make sure it works first.

Once you have a significant number of <strike>books</strike> rows and actually *see performance problems*, then is the time to revisit your schema. In most cases you will just need a few indexes to speed up lookups.  Tools like the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) query help in diagnosing what the database is doing when executing your query.

So in short, don't worry about it.